# Can't properly push comments to an array in mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, reactjs, mongoose, redux

So I am building this app that allows users to post comments.

I am running into a problem where when I try and post a comment, it doesn't actually add on to the already existing comment it just replaces the comment that was already there. I am not sure what is going wrong to make this happen.

Here is my Express route for the comment:

```
.put((req, res) => {
        Issue.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, {$push: {comments: req.body.comments}}, (err, updatedComment) => {
            if(err) return res.status(500).send(err);
            return res.send(updatedComment);
        })
    })
```

Here is my Redux where I am actually using the same action creater for when I am editing the post to add comments:

```
export const getIssues = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        axios.get("/issues").then(response => {
            dispatch({
                type: "GET_ISSUES",
                issues: response.data
            })
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        })
    }
}
export const editIssue = (editedIssue, id) => {
    return dispatch => {
        axios.put(`/issues/${id}`, editedIssue).then(response => {
            dispatch(getIssues());
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        })
    }
}

const reducer = (state = [], action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case "GET_ISSUES":
            return action.issues
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Here's the form to add a comment and the onClick method:

```
addComment = () => {
        this.props.editIssue({
            comments: this.state.comment
        }, this.props.id)
    }
<button onClick={this.toggleComment}>Add A Comment</button>
                {this.state.isCommenting ? <form>
                    <input type="text" value={this.state.comment} name="comment" placeholder="Add A Comment..." onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                    <button onClick={this.addComment}>Submit</button>
                </form>: null}
```

And finally my Schema for the post:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const issuesSchema = new Schema({
    issue: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    comments: [String]
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("Issues", issuesSchema);
```

Let me know if there is anything else from my code you would want to see. I purposefully omitted some of the code because I feel like this post is already long as is.

Comment: `Issue.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {$push: {comments: req.body.comments}}, (err, updatedComment) =>` You also had `req.body` in there where it has no such place. If you want to "overwrite" everything then just include the `req.body`. If you want to "add to comments" then only put through the comments with `$push`

Comment: Are you posting multiple comments ? I mean `req.body.comments` is it array of comments ?

Comment: @FarhanTahir It starts out as an empty array. When I try and add a comment for the first time, it works, the comment gets added to the array, but when I try and add another one it doesn't actually add on to the array, it just replaces the first comment. So essentially, I can only put one comment or else it just replaces what's already there.

Answer (score 0):

your update function will be as below, (you dont have to give req.body as argument because of it, it is updating the existing one)

```
.put((req, res) => {
        Issue.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {$push: {comments: req.body.comments}}, (err, updatedComment) => {
            if(err) return res.status(500).send(err);
            return res.send(updatedComment);
        })
    })
```

for more about [findByIdAndUpdate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html)

or try this below

```
.put((req, res) => {
    Issue.update({
        _id: req.params.id
    },
        {
            $push: {
                comments: req.body.comments
            }
        }, (err, updatedComment) => {
            if (err) return res.status(500).send(err);
            return res.send(updatedComment);
        })
})
```

for more about [update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/)
for more about [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/)

Comment: Hi, this didn't work. The exact same thing is happening.

Comment: Still nothing. Continues doing the same thing. This is a tough one.

Comment: can you update your question with current code, will see and try to resolve your issue and will guide if any syntax error